# Keras Valueerror: This model has never been called

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

This should be very simple Keras program.  It works until the last line of code.  But I have called the predict method.  Granted I used the same input data as the training data, but that should not matter.

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/werowe/logisticRegressionBestModel/master/KidCreative.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',')

labels=data['Buy']
features = data.iloc[:,2:16]

model = Sequential()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop' ,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
model.evaluate(labels, features, batch_size=128)
model.predict(labels)
model.summary()
```

But I get this error:

```python
model.summary()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/walker/tf3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1263, in summary
    'This model has never been called, this its weights '
ValueError: This model has never been called, this its weights have not yet been created, so no summary can be displayed. Build the model first (e.g. by calling it on some test data).
```

Comment: You don't seem to build any model; you sure you have no other code after `model = Sequential()` and before `model.compille`?

Comment: No.  That's the complete code, also shown here https://github.com/werowe/KerasExample/blob/master/kerasExample.py

Comment: Your model is empty, the error message is correct. You should put layers and stuff into your instance of Sequential

Answer (score 6):

The first step should be to actually *build* a model, which you don't do; i.e. after `model = Sequential()`, there should be some `model.add` statements, in order to build the model, before compiling it, fitting it, and use it for evaluation or getting its summary.

Instead of getting guidance from some repo of ambiguous quality, it's better to start from the official examples & tutorials - look for example at the [Keras MNIST CNN example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py); replicating here only the model-related parts, we get:

```python
model = Sequential()
# no model built, as in your case
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This should already give an error:

```python
TypeError: Sequential model cannot be built: model is empty. Add some layers first.
```

which I am surprised you don't report in your case.

Here is what we should do instead (again, refer to the link for the full details):

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
# works OK
```

Comment: You just copied the code directly from the  Keras MNIST CNN example.  Below is working code based on suggestion by Matias Valdenegro.

Comment: @WalkerRowe you are very welcome! Never mind that, before "just copying", I had to reproduce the error first (i.e. to modify the example & actually run the modified code), for which I needed a reliable *reproducible example* with a known problem (how was I, or anyone else for that matter, supposed to *guess* from your question that you had a 14-class classification task?), and all this takes some time, somewhat longer that a simple comment...

Answer (score 5):

As [@desertnaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685471/desertnaut) said, it is necessary to have layers in a model before calling mode.summary().

**Edit:** I want to add that, Even if your model has layers model.summary() may not work if it doesn't have "input_shape" in the first layer.

Because in Sequential model dimensions of input of each layer (thus the number of parameters) are calculated using output dimension of the preceding layer but to start this chain input dimension for the first layer is needed. So it is not possible to generate a summary of the model without the input dimension.

Note: If you don't explicitly specify input dimension than keras will figure it out when you call fit() for the first time. So if you don't specify input_shape, then you need to call model.fit() before the model.summary()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matias Valdenegro, I added some input layers and changed the loss function.  Now this works:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Dense

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/werowe/logisticRegressionBestModel/master/KidCreative.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',')

labels=data['Buy']
features = data.iloc[:,2:16]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(units=14, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(labels, features,
          batch_size=12,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(labels, features))

model.evaluate(labels, features, verbose=0)

model.summary()
```